# Double self-reference within the same entity using an extra join table

Tags: java, jpa

I want to create a double self-reference entity using an extra join table. I tried thus the following :

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "entity_a", schema="schema_a")
public class EntityA{
@Id 
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
//skipped source code...
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "origin_child",
      joinColumns = 
        { @JoinColumn(name = "origin_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)},
      inverseJoinColumns = 
        { @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)})
  private EntityA child;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "origin_child",
      joinColumns = 
        { @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)},
      inverseJoinColumns = 
        { @JoinColumn(name = "origin_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)})
  private EntityA origin;
  //skipped source code...
}
```

When running my code I get the following error : `org.hibernate.boot.spi.InFlightMetadataCollector$DuplicateSecondaryTableException: Table with that name [origin_child] already associated with entity`

I tried thus to remove the `origin` field from `EntityA` and it worked. Now I am trying to figure out a way to join my `EntityA.id` and `EntityA.origin_id` over the already existing `origin_child.child_id` and `origin_child.origin_id`. Any idea how may I achieve that. Any alternative or better solution is more than welcome.

**UPDATE** :

I have tried the `@JoinColumn` alternative as following :

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "child")
private EntityA origin;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
private EntityA child;
```

Now when trying to update both origin and child instances :

```
child.setOrigin(origin);
entityARepository.save(child);
origin.setChild(child);
entityARepository.save(origin);
```

I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError` due to infinite recursion.

Any work around please?

Comment: Could be because the two descriptions of the `origin_child` table differs. In one, the `child_id` is nullable, in the other, the `origin_id` is nullable, In reality, neither should be nullable, so either set all 4 `nullable` attributes to `false`, or just remove all 4 attributes.

Comment: *Question:* Why do you need `@JoinTable`? Why aren't they just plain `@JoinColumn`?

Comment: @Andreas I tried `@JoinColumn` but I am getting a StackOverflow error at Runtime

Comment: @Andreas I fixed the `nullable=false` in all 4 attributes, still getting the same exception message as mentioned above.

Comment: Now it is time for you to **read a guide** on how to do `@OneToOne`, e.g. see the Baeldung article [One-to-One Relationship in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one). In short, only put `@JoinColumn` on one of them, not both.

Comment: @Andreas I have modified the thread. Please have a look.

Comment: There is only one database column, so don't set'n'save both fields.

Comment: @Andreas I did what you said, still getting a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Comment: So you only call one of the `set` methods and only `save()` that object, and that causes stack overflow?

Comment: @Andreas yes exactly